# How do I use standard GWT CSS style themes from non-GWT pages?

Tags: css, gwt

I have written an GWT app and a static Intro page that introduces the app.  It is turning out to be convenient for the intro to be a separate .jsp page, rather than part of the app; however, I want the CSS styling to be the same for the app and the intro page.  How do I include the same GWT CSS style for the static or .jsp page as for the GWT app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For instance using the Clean css provided by gwt, defined in projectname.gwt.xml:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
```

Your css will be stored in:

/projectname/gwt/clean/clean.css

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

just include it like a standard webpage like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{Path to css here}"/>
```

Comment: I know that.  The question was: where is the style sheet.

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear, OK if using a theme simply look in the {theme}.gwt.xml file for something like, `<stylesheet src="gwt/chrome/chrome.css"/>` and follow the path from there